# osgi exporting of implementation for inheritance

Tags: java, osgi, osgi-bundle

Based on best practices I've read in different places ([one example](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/techjournal/1007_charters/1007_charters.html)), it is ideal to separate API and implementation but also to only export packages in the API bundle and not in the implementation bundle, which should register as a service instead.

However I'm still not clear how are you supposed to extend a concrete class. It seems to me that to be able to do

```
class Child extends com.foo.ParentImpl {
}
```

the impl bundle would need to expose `com.foo`

AFAIU there are only two ways

1. Export the concrete implementation, but this violates the best practices
2. Never extend classes from a different bundle. i.e bundle all the type hierarchy together. This kind of defeats the point of a modularity framework in my opinion

So what is the right way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can expose the implementation class as an export — OSGi will not prevent you from doing so. Just be aware that you are violating the best practice.

You may argue that best practices are meant to be broken, and in some cases you'd be right. However, this one really does exist for a good reason! Inheritance in Java creates a very tight coupling between the base- and sub-classes. By allowing other bundles to have visibility of your implementation classes and potentially subclass them, then you **severely** restrict your ability to make implementation changes in the base class. Essentially the implementation *is* the API, and so cannot be changed in the future.

So my advice would be to forget about inheritance. It's overrated.

If you really want to do it, then keep the hierarchy together, as per your option number 2.

Comment: thank you Neil. I also agree with you that inheritance is overrated

Answer (score 2):

TLDR: Separating out API and Implementation is best left for things that you are exposed as OSGI services whose *instances* will be referenced from bundles. Otherwise just expose your class as-is.

The type of modularity you get in OSGI doesn't lend itself well to extending Service classes. You are much better off using some design pattern that will
allow you to extend the functionality of your services.

I would also like to know what class you are trying to extend and what it's purpose is.

Now if you absolutely must extend a service class outside of the bundle, your best bet may be to delegate.

```
 class MyExtendedService implements Service {
    Service service;
    //delegate to MyService which also implements Service and
    //  is pulled from another osgi bundle.
 }
```

Now if you are defining classes that are 'things', like Models or Value Object, there is probably no reason to have separate API and Implementation classes. Just expose them as is.